# java, writing data size with DataOutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream, dataoutputstream

I have a series of objects which write their data out to a file via DataOutputStream.

As my application file format evolves, I will be adding further data objects to it, which should be able to be read by "older" versions of the application.

To be able to do this, I am needing to preface the objects data with a size value indicating the number of bytes that the current object will take up.

However, as this data can be a variable size, notably when handling strings, I cannot know beforehand what the size will be.

Is there a way to "pre-write" to a byte buffer, as if it were a DataOutputStream (*methods in particular - writeByte, writeShort, writeInt, writeUTF*) which will enable me to get back the byte length of the data before writing it out to the DataOutputStream ?  Doing this will enable me to skip over newer data objects that older versions of the application does understand.

Comment: Are you serializing objects yourself, or using java's built in serialization?

Comment: Do you need to store the data in binary format, or could you marshal your data objects into text, e.g. JSON or YAML with a library like Jackson? Deserialization should also become quite simple when using a library for the heavy lifting.

Comment: If you're serializing it yourself, I use [this](https://github.com/PlutoPowered/Nebula/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gmail/socraticphoenix/nebula/io/Bytes.java#L29) technique to serialize strings, but you could potentially use null termination as well

Comment: I am serializing objects myself.  I am NOT using any form of text serialisation.  This is therefore a binary format, hence the need to be able to ascertain the data size.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Java serialization is not that great for a variety of reasons. One of the most important ones is that it's very brittle, and tends not to be "future proof". If possible, I'd suggest you use a different serialization format, especially if you specifically mention that you plan on adding fields to the class you serialize.

Formats such as [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), and [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) have Java libraries with nice APIs, and good forwards/backwards compatibility features. In most cases, it would be far simpler to Serialize your data into a more convenient format, than solving the problems of the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object), you could use `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation` in this way:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

and then calculate the size in bytes of your object:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
   Object myObject = ...;
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(myObject));
    }
```

Comment: Looks interesting. However it is not the size of the object I am looking for but the size, or length, of binary data which will be written out.